# iText - generating files on the fly without needing a PDF file

Tags: java, jsp, itext

I am trying to use iText for pdf file generation and I have a question regarding the generation. I would like to serve the PDF to the browser so that the browser displays it, without actually creating a file.

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

One limitation is that I would need to use it from a JSP page - something that would circumvent the "getOutputStream has already been called once" error is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I would like to serve the PDF to the browser so that the browser displays it, without actually creating a file.*

Just pass `responsegetOutputStream()` instead of `new FileOutputStream` to `PdfWriter`.

```
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
// ...
```

---

> *One limitation is that I would need to use it from a JSP page - something that would circumvent the "getOutputStream has already been called once" error is what I am looking for.*

Just remove **any** whitespace outside `<% %>` in JSP, including newlines. They are implicitly sent to the response by the response writer.

I.e. do NOT

```
<% page import="foo" %>
<% page import="bar" %>

<%
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
       out.println("I should not use scriptlets.");
   }
%>

(newline here)
```

but more so

```
<% page import="foo" %><% page import="bar" %><%
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
       out.println("I should use servlets.");
   }
%>
```

Or better, don't put Java code in JSP files. JSP files are designed to present template text like HTML, not to do entirely different things. Do that in a normal Java class like a servlet.

Comment: BalusC - thank you very much for your effort to answer my question. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Write it to the servlet output stream, remembering to set the encoding to the correct value

Comment: Here is the code that I am trying to run: 
=====================
    Document document = new Document();
            // step 2
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
            // step 3
            document.open();
            // step 4
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));


==============================================================
itext getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Comment: I have some code that does this, but I won't get to post t until the morning - ill do it then

Comment: Haven't forgotten about this - I'm still trying to find the relevant code

Comment: Thank you sir. I have already done this in a servlet, but the requirements are to do it in a JSP page - I am just looking for ways to circumvent the problem with the getOutputStream being already called for the response.

Comment: BalusC has already given you the answer above, so all I'd be doing is repeating what he's said. Let us know how it works out for you

Answer (score 2):

This http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/06/18/dynamic_files.html explains how to do it