# Convert Outputstream to file

Tags: java, html, jsp, pdf, vraptor

Well i'm stucked with a problem,

I need to create a PDF with a html source and i did this way:

```
File pdf = new File("/home/wrk/relatorio.pdf");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pdf);
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(build.toString().getBytes());//Build is a StringBuilder obj
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(input, null);
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

well i'm using JSP so i need to download this file to the user not write in the server...

How do I transform this Outputstream output to a file in the java without write this file in hard drive ?

Comment: You want to write to a file and not have this file on hard drive? I don't get your question

Comment: I need to download the pdf not write in the hard drive.

Comment: downloading a file means storing it into hard drive...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268165/itext-generating-files-on-the-fly-without-needing-a-pdf-file/9296669#9296669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using VRaptor 3.3.0+ you can use the `ByteArrayDownload` class. Starting with your code, you can use this:

```
@Path("/download-relatorio")
public Download download() {
    // Everything will be stored into this OutputStream
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(build.toString().getBytes());
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(input, null);
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    // Now that you have finished, return a new ByteArrayDownload()
    // The 2nd and 3rd parameters are the Content-Type and File Name
    // (which will be shown to the end-user)
    return new ByteArrayDownload(out.toByteArray(), "application/pdf", "Relatorio.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `File` object does not actually hold the data but delegates all operations to the file system (see [this discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/530887//java/Create-virtual-file)).
You could, however, create a temporary file using [`File.createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597646/java-servlet-and-io-create-a-file-without-saving-to-disk-and-sending-it-to-the) for a possible alternative without using a `File` object.

Answer (score -1):

use temporary files.

```
File temp = File.createTempFile(prefix ,suffix);
```

prefix -- The prefix string defines the files name; must be at least three characters long.

suffix -- The suffix string defines the file's extension; if null the suffix ".tmp" will be used.