# Scribus, IText reduce file size

Tags: pdf, itext, ghostscript

I'm generating PDFs using IText within a webapp.  The PDF files come from Scribus, and are huge (2MB for one page).  The current approach is that the PDF has lots of form fields, which then get populated by IText (AcroForms, etc.)

The individual PDF generated by Scribus is 2MB.  It could be as small as 150K.  I know that due to having run GhostScript on it.  See below.

For large files (some could be 150 pages), the server bogs down, and often no PDF results.

GhostScript will reduce the file to 150K per page.  But, I can't run that as a post-process if the PDF generation never completes.  If I run GhostScript on the initial PDF that gets fed to IText, then the form fields go away, and the result is an empty form.

So, I either need a way to run GhostScript without losing the form fields (or another external tool that does the same thing), or a way for IText to populate a PDF via some means other than form fields.  Is there any IText feature equivalent to good old JavaScript's document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML = "new text";?

Of course, the absolute best solution would be an export option in Scribus that would simply not do the "place one glyph at a time" that they are so proud of.

Comment: What exactly do you do with ghostscript to reduce the file size?

Comment: What version of Ghostscript are you using ? I believe AcroForms should be preserved if you supply the -dShowAcroForm switch (see use.htm). Perhaps you could share an example file at each stage of the process  from Scribus, from iText and from PDF.

Comment: Here is the bat file I use to apply Ghostscript:

"c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin64.exe"  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dShowAcroForm -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=%1_1.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f %1.pdf

Also tried it with -dShowAcroForm=true

Comment: After installing the Acrobat free trial, I got a look inside the pdf.  For some reason it has 1.8MB of fonts, which seems way too much. And then those were apparently getting repeated for each page.  Switching to PdfSmartCopy from PdfCopyFields seems to prevent the font repeating. I guess when they deprecated PdfCopyFields, the reference that they forgot to put in the Javadoc was to PdfCopy/PdfSmartCopy

Comment: Here you got the solution. [https://stackoverflow.com/q/9268165/7538821](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9268165/7538821)

Comment: That isn't actually a solution to my question.
What I finally did was write my own parser for .sla files that built the pdf from the form tags, etc., and the data that would have been used to populate them